# How do I pass data from the controller to a view in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp

While working on `cakephp` I am trying to pass the data from controller to view.
In controller,i tried:

```
 $this->set('posts',$this->Post->find('all'));
```

I am confused about the terms and its meaning of 'all' and 'find'.
Any good tutorials or links for this purpose?

Comment: book.cakephp.org - Do the blog tutorial there. It will cover all kinds of basics in CakePHP and MVC.

Comment: You can read more about Controller::set (or $this->set()) here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller::set

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->set('posts',$this->Post->find('all'));
```

is equal to:

```
SELECT * FROM POST
```

Means that you find all posts inside your database and insert it inside an array called `posts`.
To view this record in your view you can do something like this:

```
foreach($posts as $post){
   echo'<p>'.$post['Post']['id'].'</p>';
}
```

Comment: all means , what querys  we  written in model page na.. It will select all querys inside of model page .Am i right?

Comment: is equal to SELECT * FROM POST @user3106927

Comment: ok ok I understood clearly thanks u so much  @Alessandro Minoccheri

Comment: Glad to help you, accept and uvote the answer when you can(about 3 minutes) to help other guys with your same problem @user3106927